# S3 Concurrent Writes Behavior

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

Last time I checked, S3 had undefined behavior for concurrent writes. I'm using a queue service that enforces at-least-once delivery so I sometimes end up concurrently writing to the same prefix 2+ times. What possible outcomes could there be from writing to the same prefix at the exact same time? I'm assuming the following cases are possible:

1. One of the two writes succeeds leading to a new file
2. Neither of the writes succeeds which means no new file in S3

Is there a 3rd possible case that results in an unusable corrupted S3 file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing there still isn't any confirmation that S3 is planning on handling this behaviour and a quick search didn't yield any results for me.

Wouldn't you be better off dealing with  yourself? If S3 isn't guaranteeing any specifics it sounds like it falls upon your design to solve the problem? Each message has an ID that you can use to recognise when you've received a duplicate. I guess you'll have to use a consistent system in between to guarantee you only write each object to S3 once.

Comment: Handling this myself is one good option. I'm using an autoscaling kubernetes cluster to dequeue so I'd have to coordinate between containers. I'm also using retries so only uploading corrupted files would be a potential issue. Depending on how frequently files are corrupted, it might not be worth it to change the design.

Comment: You could maintain a consistent DB instance somewhere and use that if you want to coordinate between containers. I guess you could also 'suck it and see' but I'm not sure how eager I'd be to let AWS deal with it, that behaviour could change at any time. Just my two cents. Hopefully they'll clear this up in time!